# NSURL "URLByAppendingPathExtension:" bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

`NSURL`'s `URLByAppendingPathExtension:` doesn't seem to be acting properly for me. I am trying to add a path to the end of an existing URL. For example:

```
[[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"/10392983/example"]
```

Should be returning an URL with http://www.example.com/10392983/example according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathExtension:). Instead, it is escaping the slashes. I can achieve the same result converting to the URL to an absolute string and using regular NSString operations, but the above seems like it would be a lot more elegant. Any ideas as to which NSURL method to use to achieve this result or is this truly a bug?

Answer (score 4):

For what you are trying to do, you should use:

```
URLByAppendingPathComponent
```

According to the docs, `URLByAppendingPathExtension` is for extensions like .html. It's a little vague, but from the docs:

> If the original URL ends with one or more forward slashes, these are
>   removed from the returned URL. A period is inserted between the two
>   parts of the new URL.

This makes me think that this should only be used for *appending things like .html and .php to URLs. Just use `URLByAppendingPathComponent` instead.*

Answer (score 4):

NSURLs can get confusing and weird.

Documentation for `URLByAppendingPathExtension` says that:

"If the original URL ends with one or more forward slashes, these are removed from the returned URL. A period is inserted between the two parts of the new URL."

"removed from the returned URL" implies that these '/' forward slash characters will be replaced with their escaped counterparts (that is a % sign for forward slashes).

UrlByAppendingPathComponent from @scott's answer does not appear to work in my tests? The method needs to be spelled 'URLByAppendingPathComponent' with a capitalized 'URL' and not the lowercase 'Url' .

Try this:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[@"https://www.example.com" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/10392983/example"]]
```

That will produce the NSURL with a similar level of elegance-complexity. You can also tack on any number of "stringByAppendingPathComponent" methods to produce your NSURL.

Conversely here's an example of scott's code above:

```
NSURL*combined = [baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: stringPath];
```

Comment: The thing is I am utilizing URLs and don't want to do the conversions back and forth between NSString. I have a "Base URL"(https://www.example.com) and the above would require translating to an NSString, point is, I want to be able to create new URLs from a URL without added complexity. In addition, in my example, you mention "if the URL ends in one or more forward slashes" and in my test, it didn't end in any forward slashes.

Comment: Your original code takes two strings as input, the answer takes two strings as input. My suggestion uses the same number of strings as your original answer and produces an NSURL. I mean if you don't want to use strings at all then you should not use [NSURL URLWithString:@""]. There really isn't any method that lets you create an NSURL without first feeding it some kind of string. You could try:                                      NSURL* first = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"];
    NSURL* second = [first URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"/10392983/example"];

Comment: For the sake of the example, I included both strings, but the NSURL was being generated. My point is, I am trying to manipulate a NSURL object.

Comment: So you would like to do "NSURL + NSURL = NEWNSURL"? I don't think that will work; An NSURL is not a sequence of words with slashes, it's a url. In other words, "https://www.example.com" would be a valid thing to store in an NSURL, but "/10392983/example" would not really be a valid thing to store in an NSURL, because it is not a url. So there wouldn't really be a way to store that second thing in as an NSURL.

Comment: I am trying to do NSURL (base URL) + NSString (path) = NSURL (combined), without having to convert the base URL to a string. Ideally, a method such as "URLByAppendingPathExtension:" would do this.

Comment: Alright so @scott's answer is probably the most useful for you then: NSURL*combined = [baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: stringPath]; Where baseURL is some pre determined URL and stringPath is your NSString. This seems to be exactly what you have been asking for. I have edited my answer to show an example.